# Error: Framework '.NETFramework 4.0 Client Profile' not installed. for MonoDevelop 2.8.1

Tags: .net, monodevelop

I get the following error:

```
Error: Framework '.NETFramework 4.0 Client Profile' not installed.
```

When I try to build my project.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You probably need the multitargetting framework package (I remember seeing that as part of the VS install).

Comment: Where can I get this and how do I install it for MonoDevelop on Mac?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

MSBuild projects can reference arbitrary framework profiles (subsets), which will only work if the profile is installed in the runtime's frameworks definitions. Mono doesn't have all of the framework profiles that .NET has, e.g. the .NET 4.0 Client Profile.

To work around this, change the project to use the full 4.0 framework.

In MonoDevelop, here's how you change the setting:

1. Click on project name
2. Right click on each Assembly (for e.g. "Assembly-CSharp")
3. Options > Build > General > Target Framework
4. Select a framework that is installed on your computer.
5. Do this for all assemblies used in the project (usually it's 3 ).

Comment: If anyone else is having trouble, the way to do this is

1) Right click on project name
2) Options > Build > General > Target Framework