# MAC OS X Mono Error: Framework '.NETFramework 4.0 Client Profile' not installed

Tags: c#, macos, monodevelop

I use Mac OS X 10.8 & MonoDevelop 3.0.4.7 to code C# project. How can I solve this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The search function is your friend, have a look at this:
[Error: Framework '.NETFramework 4.0 Client Profile' not installed. for MonoDevelop 2.8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181081/error-framework-netframework-4-0-client-profile-not-installed-for-monodevel)

Mono does not come with all profiles that are used in .NET  try using .NET 4.0 full profile